# How to retrieve yahoo search results?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to search Yahoo for a query using this code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

query = "deep"
yahoo = "https://search.yahoo.com/search?q=" + query + "&n=" + str(10)
raw_page = requests.get(yahoo)

soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_page.text)

for link in soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "ac-algo fz-l ac-21th lh-24"}):
    print (link.text, link.get('href'))
```

But this does not work and the result is empty. How can I get 10 first search results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the main problems with your code:

- When using Beautiful soup you should always include a [parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) *(e.g. `BeautifulSoup(raw_page.text, "lxml")`)*
- You were searching for the wrong class, it's  `" ac-algo fz-l ac-21th lh-24"` not `"ac-algo fz-l ac-21th lh-24"` *(notice the space in the begining)*

All in all your code should look like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

query = "deep"
yahoo = "https://search.yahoo.com/search?q=" + query + "&n=" + str(10)
raw_page = requests.get(yahoo)

soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_page.text, "lxml")
for link in soup.find_all(attrs={"class": " ac-algo fz-l ac-21th lh-24"}):
    print(link.text, link.get('href'))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you for your answer. Actually, I tried with space at the beginning and it didn't work. When I remove the space, it works!!!
Is there any option in **soup** to filter the links, so that ad or youtube links are ignored?

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad As far as I know you can't if I were you I would do it inside of the for loop (using if statements) :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Css Selector to find all links which is must faster.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

query = "deep"
yahoo = "https://search.yahoo.com/search?q=" + query + "&n=" + str(10)
raw_page = requests.get(yahoo)

soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_page.text,'lxml')

for link in soup.select(".ac-algo.fz-l.ac-21th.lh-24"):
    print (link.text, link['href'])
```

Output :

```
(Deep | Definition of Deep by Merriam-Webster', 'https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deep')
(Connecticut Department of Energy & Environmental Protection', 'https://www.ct.gov/deep/site/default.asp')
(Deep | Define Deep at Dictionary.com', 'https://www.dictionary.com/browse/deep')
(Deep - definition of deep by The Free Dictionary', 'https://www.thefreedictionary.com/deep')
(Deep (2017) - IMDb', 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4105584/')
(Deep Synonyms, Deep Antonyms | Merriam-Webster Thesaurus', 'https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/deep')
(Deep Synonyms, Deep Antonyms | Thesaurus.com', 'https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/deep')
(DEEP: Fishing - Connecticut', 'https://www.ct.gov/deep/cwp/view.asp?q=322708')
(Deep Deep Deep - YouTube', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZhwagxWzOc')
(deep - English-Spanish Dictionary - WordReference.com', 'https://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=deep')
```

Comment: faster is soup.select(".ac-algo")

Comment: @QHarr : yes completely agree with you.